# JavaScript splitting a file content into key value pairs

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the below UploadDocument event which has fileReader.result which logs below message to the console

**Output in the Console**

```
A,B
aa,dsf
adfa,dfsd
fdsafds,sdf

 uploadDocument(file) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
     fileReader.onload =(e) => {
      console.log(fileReader.result);
    }  
    fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
```

How can I split the above content (A,B...) in the console into a key value pairs ( Like a hashmap or Arraylist ) using javascript or Typescript?

I have tried splitting it
  var lines = fileReader.result.split(/[\r\n]+/g); 
      console.log(lines);

Now how can I create A hashmap from this?

Comment: `Array.split` by '\n' and then `Array.reduce` (splitting inside the callback again by `,`) using `{}` as an accumulator.

Comment: If lodash is an option, you could do the whole transformation in one chain: `_.chain(fileReader.result).split('\n').map(line => _.split(line, ',')).fromPairs().value()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) array method can be used to build objects over each element, so we just need to split the file into multiple lines and then reduce the array of lines into an object.

```
var map = fileReader.result.split('\n')
    .reduce((obj, line) => {
        var cols = line.split(',');
        // Tolerate empty lines. There may be one at the end of the input.
        if (cols.length >= 2) {
            obj[cols[0]] = cols[1];
        }
        return obj;
    }, {});
```

[Sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cdhowie/ws0w8Lxx/)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which takes an initial value - in this case a new object - and populates its keys and values with the result of splitting each line in the file on the comma with each iteration of the function.

```js
const input = 'A,B\n\
aa,dsf\n\
adfa,dfsd\n\
fdsafds,sdf'

const obj = input.split(/\n/g).reduce((acc, c) => {
  const [first, second] = c.split(',');
  acc[first] = second;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```